# Update datetime attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

I'd like to update a datetime attribute using two elements on a form: a text_field and a time_select.  This would enable the user to select the date using a datepicker (jquery ui) and the time using drop down menus:

[image]

However, when I try to update update my form, I get the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::MultiparameterAssignmentErrors in StepsController#update

1 error(s) on assignment of multiparameter attributes

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"put",
 "authenticity_token"=>"FxFbv9OFzCiYjNknZKUtwyAXR99uuOvy8uplv1cKaZE=",
 "step"=>{"description"=>"<p>Project description</p>\r\n",
 "published_on"=>"05/30/2013",
 "published_on(4i)"=>"15",
 "published_on(5i)"=>"19"},
 "commit"=>"Update Step",
 "project_id"=>"92",
 "id"=>"0"}
```

How can I combine the parameters from a text_field and a time_select into one datetime?

Here is my form:

```
<%= f.text_field :published_on, :value=> (@step.published_on.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")) %>  at <%= f.time_select :published_on, :class=>"btn dropdown-toggle", :ampm=> true, :ignore_date=>true %>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a scenario which ViewModels could be useful but getting into it would be overkill.

So the best options that comes to my mind is merging values on client side, or  on server side merging the values just before building the object from `params` variable.

On server side it can be implemented using Action Controller Filters:
`before_filter :merge_somefileds!, only: [:edit]`

For more: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters

Comment: thanks for your help.  I'm trying to get the parameters in my controller from my time_select form, but it's not working correctly.  If the parameter is published_on(4i), how can I get this in my controller?  I currently  have:   publish_hour = params['published_on(4i)'] on my controller

Comment: just start a debug session and inspect the params variable, if you don't know how to do that, checkout the pry project at https://github.com/pry/pry